# How to manage the 'where' clause in Prisma?

Tags: typescript, nest, prisma

I am studying Prisma, and I have experience using QueryDSL with JPA. I would like to extract the "where" clause from the following code into a single object, similar to QueryDSL. I'm curious if there is a good way to do this. Thank you so much for your response.

```java
    public List<MemberTeamDto> findByCondition(SearchCond cond){

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
        if(cond.getUsername() != null){
            builder.and(member.username.eq(cond.getUsername()));
        }
        if(cond.getTeamName() != null){
            builder.and(team.name.eq(cond.getTeamName()));
        }
        if (cond.getAgeGoe() != null){
            builder.and(member.age.goe(cond.getAgeGoe()));
        }
        if (cond.getAgeLoe() != null){
            builder.and(member.age.loe(cond.getAgeLoe()));
        }


        return queryFactory.select(
                new QMemberTeamDto(
                        member.id.as("memberId"),
                        member.age,
                        member.username,
                        team.name.as("teamName")
                        ))
                .from(member)
                .leftJoin(member.team , team)
                .where(builder)
                .fetch();
    }
```

to prisma

```js
const todayUploadImageCount = await prisma.challengeImage.count({
          where: {
            memberId: { in: memberIds.map((memberId) => memberId.id) },
            createdAt: todayDate,
            deletedAt: null,
          },
        });
```

"I want to use externally created conditions in my query instead of adding conditions directly in the query."